# How to change the component on mouse hover without using routing

Tags: angular

I want to change the components on mouse hover without using routing. when I have house hover on text component then text component called and when I mouse hover on button component then button component called or text component hide.

Comment: I think you have to clarify what exactly you would like to achieve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show and hide component on 'mouseover' event. 
Html:

```
<div class="tab">
  <div class="tablinks" (mouseover)="onMouseover(0)">text</div><br>
  <button class="tablinks" (mouseover)="onMouseover(1)">Button</button><br><br>
  <input type="radio" class="tablinks" (mouseover)="onMouseover(2)">Bulk Transmit
</div>
<div>
  <app-sports  *ngIf="tabIndex === 0"></app-sports>
  <app-movies  *ngIf="tabIndex === 2"></app-movies>
</div>
```

Script

```
tabIndex = 2 ;

onMouseover(index){
  this.tabIndex = index;
}
```

[Check Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ba5utr)